# How to check an input for a specific data type?

Tags: c

I am at very and i mean very beginnings of C programming, but i have a question that is prohibiting me to move further.

I was making an addition of two numbers program in C and i used the following code :

```
# include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a,b,c;

    printf("Enter no. 1 \n");
    scanf("%d",&a);

    printf("Enter no. 2 \n");
    scanf("%d",&b);

    {
        c=a+b;
    }
    printf("The sum is %d\n", c);

    return (0);
}
```

Now, as i ran the program with a few inputs, it ran just fine.
But when i entered a string it came out something like this.

[Output addition_int](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Q9hz.png)

Can anyone please tell me how to check if the input gained is an integer and add it as an argument. A possible if else statement ? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: `scanf()` has a return value that will help you

Comment: you could use the macros defined in the header file `ctype.h` and/or you could make use of the functions like `strtol()` which will tell you if a problem occurred

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  2)  variable names should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both).  Names like a, b, c are meaningless, even in the current context

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  Note: those functions return a count of how many input conversions were successfully performed

Answer (score 1):

You should use the return value of scanf.

> int std::scanf( const char* format, ... );
>
> **Return value**
>
> Number of receiving arguments successfully assigned.
>
> --- from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf)

Full Code:

```
# include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a, b, c;

    printf("Enter no. 1 \n");
    while(scanf("%d", &a) != 1)
        getchar();

    printf("Enter no. 2 \n");
    while(scanf("%d", &b) != 1)
        getchar();

    c = a + b;
    printf("The sum is %d\n", c);
    return 0;
}
```

So when `scanf` fails to read a decimal, it'll return `0`. So we need to use `getchar` to remove the non-decimal character and continue to receive the decimal input.

The strange `c` value you got is because of the failing `scanf`, it'll keep the `a` value unassigned, so it will be some garbage value.

Answer (score 0):

> How to check an input for a specific data type?
>   ... when i entered a string it came out something like this. ...
>   how to check if the input gained is an integer ...

User input is not *strings* nor integer nor some specific type.  User input is *text* (a sequence of characters) including control codes like `'\n'`.  `scanf()` takes this text and converts it.

How `scanf()`converts depends on the *format* string.

`scanf("%d",&a);` will attempt to consume the input text and convert to an `int` and save that value to the place pointed to by `&a`.  If text is entered that does not conform to a expected sequence like *optional spaces* + *optional sign* + *digits*, then input is left in `stdin` for the next input operation.

Code can detect conversion success by the return value of `scanf()` which is usually the number of completed conversions.

```
int completed_conversions = scanf("%d",&a);
if (completed_conversions == 1) {
  puts("An `int` was read");
} else if (completed_conversions == 0) {
  puts("Non numerical input detected, nothing read, `a` unchanged");
} else if (completed_conversions == EOF) {
  puts("End-of-file or rare input error occurred");
}
```

Now what to do if text input does not make sense for an `int`?  Perhaps throw away all input until the end of the line (or end-of-file) and try again.

```
while (scanf("%d",&a) != 1) {
  int ch;
  puts("Let us try again.");
  while ((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n') {
    if (ch == EOF) {
      puts("End of file or error - let's go home.");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } 
  }
}
```